# Why htaccess starts with dot

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am studying the apache's `.htaccess` file and understands the concepts behind it. I followed some good tutorials/articles but there is no any clear explanation of it that why htaccess started with dot (`.htaccess)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The dot makes it a hidden file, and it usually isn't able to be read publicly. These are for security reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These types of files are called [Dot Files](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/dot_file.htm).

A file that starts with a dot denotes a hidden file, which is generally used for configuration purposes. You can find a list of other common Dot Files [here.](http://kb.iu.edu/data/afyy.html)

Answer (score 2):

On *nix systems, a `.` at the beginning of a filename means that it is a hidden file. I'd assume that apache means to signal that this is not a normal page of the website, hence uses a hidden file.